# Can I ask about internships?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to ask this question in this site. I didn't know where else to ask this.

"I have decided to switch my career. I want to enter into the fitness world.
I see myself as a fitness instructor.
Can anyone please let me know if internships are offered in any fitness institutes?
My choice would be to go on the body-weight courses, kettlebell courses or courses related to athletics. 
Doesn't matter which part of the world. The money is a big deal to me but I will manage accordingly.

Any suggestions related to this would be helpful."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there would be one "timeless" answer of internships at fitness institutes. Internships programs may stop or change at any time the institute's discretion given that the institution is still running.

A question of this type will provide too many answers to broadly narrow it down specifically. Unfortunately, I think you will have to do this research on your own.